# Erro de sintaxe MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sintaxe

Estou fazendo um formulário para inserir dados em meu banco dados porém a função que faz isso está me retornando um erro de sintaxe que não consigo encontrar.

Função

```
function insereProduto($conexao, $nome, $descricao, $tamanho, $quantidade)
{
$query = "insert into uniformes (nome, descricao, tamanho , quantidade)
    values ('.$nome.', '.$descricao.', '.$tamanho.', .$quantidade.);";
return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}
```

Erro:

```
O produto Camisa Polo não foi adicionado: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.)' at line 2
```

Comment: Troque esses pontos por chaves. Parece que você fez uma concatenação bem errada no seu comando SQL.

Comment: Eu coloquei esses pontos porque estava dando errado quando eu utilizava as chaves

Comment: Bizarro que agora foi :|

Comment: bizzarro é envolver umas variaveis com aspas simples e ponto   e $quantidade só com pontos hahaha. Não estou dizendo que iria funcionar mas não houve uniformidade na sintaxe. Se envolver todas só com aspas simples funciona também.

Comment: tentei colocar os pontos porque um cara me ajudou aqui no sistema de login e o código tinha ficado com ' . ' `$query       = "select * from usuarios where email='".$email."'";`

Comment: Mas veja que entre as aspas simples ainda existem as aspas duplas, para sair da *string* e efetuar a concatenação. Você não colocou essas aspas duplas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está no que parece ter feito uma concatenação PHP dentro de uma *string*:

```
$query = "insert into uniformes (nome, descricao, tamanho , quantidade) values ('.$nome.', '.$descricao.', '.$tamanho.', .$quantidade.);";
```

Você definiu uma *string* com aspas duplas e utilizou o operador de concatenação, `.`, dentro desta *string*. Desta forma, o PHP não analisa tal operador, deixando o caractere ponto no comando SQL, gerando o erro de sintaxe. Você pode apenas substituir os pontos por chaves:

```
$query = "insert into uniformes (nome, descricao, tamanho , quantidade) values ('{$nome}', '{$descricao}', '{$tamanho}', {$quantidade})";
```

Indicando ao PHP para analisar a *string* e substituir as variáveis por seus respectivos valores.